# Utilizing Comparable for 2 Sort Criteria when Sorting an Array of Objects

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, methods

I've been working at this for a couple hours now and I feel (I hope) I'm right on the verge of figuring it out.  This program reads in a bunch of values from an external file and places them in an array of objects which seems to be working just fine.

The Objects properties are:
Bank Account #
Customer Name
Bank Account Balance

**1.** I can output them in order of Account # (That's how their read in from the file, no sorting is necessary)

**2.** I've setup a method from implementing Comparable to sort by Bank Account Balance and it's working fine.

**3.** I need a second sort method, to sort by Customer Name.
     - The problem I'm having with this is based on the research I've done and what I've tried I've come to the conclusion that the only way to make this work will be to build my own Comparable Objects (sorry if my terminology is skewed.) I've attempted this as well multiple times with both Java Doc and some similar questions on SE.

When all is said and done I'm going to throw some Listeners into my checkbox group to allow the user to toggle the different sort methods.

Here's the chunks i'm working on:

```
 public class bankAccounts implements Comparable<bankAccounts> {
/* PRIVATE FIELDS HERE, FOLLOWED BY TYPICAL GET AND SET METHODS */

 /*SORTS BY ACCOUNT BALANCE WORKING GREAT*/
 public int compareTo(bankAccounts b)   {
    if (accountBalance < b.accountBalance)
    {
        return -1;
    }
    if (accountBalance > b.accountBalance)  {
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}


       /* BEGIN SNIPPET OF MAIN CLASS */


      /*METHOD I CALL FROM MAIN CLASS, SORTS BY BALANCE ^^ AS SEEN ABOVE */
Arrays.sort(retrievedAccounts);
for (int i=0; i<retrievedAccounts.length; i++)  {
    String resultFull = Integer.toString(retrievedAccounts[i].getAccountNumber()) + retrievedAccounts[i].getAccountLastName() + Double.toString(retrievedAccounts[i].getAccountBalance());
        box.append(resultFull + "\n");
}

/* NORMAL METHOD WHICH OUTPUTS IN ORDER OF ACCOUNT NUMBER, NO SORTING HAPPENING HERE */
        for(int x = 0; x < retrievedAccounts.length; ++x)
{
    String resultFull=Integer.toString(retrievedAccounts[x].getAccountNumber()) + retrievedAccounts[x].getAccountLastName() + Double.toString(retrievedAccounts[x].getAccountBalance());
    box.append("\n\n\n" + resultFull + "\n\n");
}
```

I'm hoping someone will have some insight towards a next step which might allow me to finish this up.  If you have suggestions to take this a completely different direction I'm open to that as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an idea haven't tested.

Create a another private method to store compareType

```
public class bankAccounts implements Comparable<bankAccounts> {

private int compareType = 0; // 0 - compare by balance 1-compare by name
```

In your compare method

```
public int compareTo(bankAccounts b)   {
if(this.compareType == 0){
if (accountBalance < b.accountBalance)
{
    return -1;
}
if (accountBalance > b.accountBalance)  {
    return 1;
}
return 0;
}else{
 return customerName.compareTo(b.customerName)
}
```

Comment: Okay, So it's even closer now.... It's respecting the compareType Variable (AWESOME!)Still isnt sorting names right.. I think I have something wrong with my .compareTo() methods?
`public int compareTo(bankAccounts b) {
  if(this.compareType == 0) {
  if (accountBalance < b.accountBalance)
  {
   return -1;
  }
  if (accountBalance > b.accountBalance) {
   return 1;
  }
  return 0;
  } else {
   if(accountLastName.compareTo(b.accountLastName) > 0)
   {
    return -1;
   }
   
   if(accountLastName.compareTo(b.accountLastName) < 0)
   {
    return 1;
   }
   return 0;
  }
 }`

Comment: when you test by name you have to set compareType equals to 1. did you try with that ?

Comment: Yes. I'm passing 1 to a getCompareType() method I built and I know it's working because it's bypassing the sort by Balance.  Additionally when I pass 0 to the getCompareType() method it sorts by balance.  I think there may be something wrong with my `(accountLastName.compareTo(b.accountLastName) > 0) { return -1; }` statements.  I'm doing some research now to see If i can figure it out.

Comment: I think you have to return 1 not -1 for (accountLastName.compareTo(b.accountLastName) > 0) and wise versa

Comment: Swapped the return values.  It's working perfectly!  Thank you!

This will be great for the listeners I have to build too because now they simply alter an int value rather than having to call methods.  Thanks null!

Answer (score 0):

Use an implementation of `Comparator<bankAccounts>` that compares the names of your objects and pass that into the [`Arrays.sort()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort%28T%5B%5D,%20java.util.Comparator%29) method.

Use an anonymous class like this:

```
Arrays.sort(retrievedAccounts, new Comparator<bankAccounts>() {
    public int compare(bankAccounts a, bankAccounts b) {
        return a.getName().compareTo(b.getName());
    }
});
```

This code assumes you have a getter method on `bankAccounts` for customer name called `getName()`

You would do well to follow java naming conventions:

- class names start with a capital letter
- class names are singular, not plurals

Comment: Trying this now.  Thank you!

Comment: I certainly have knowledge gaps preventing me from understanding how to implement this.  So the `return name.compareTo(b.name);`  Routes to a compareTo that I build inside of the bankAccounts class?

Comment: @Josh My bad - I coded the wrong method (I was using my iphone and going from memory). Check out the answer now.